# MySQL JOIN to fetch one result in one table and many in another

Tags: mysql

I have one table linked to another one (One-To-many (1:N) relationship). I'm trying to fetch the results from both tables with JOIN in MySQL, like so:

```
SELECT * 
FROM parent_table 
JOIN child_table 
ON (parent_table_id = child_table_id) 
WHERE parent_table_id = ?
```

Problem is that I can see the results from the parent table and only one result from the child table. How can I do to get one result from the parent table and all results from the child?

Comment: This is because it is one to one relation. Do you mean a recursive query to get the other childs in the hierarchy? Please show some sample data from the both of the tables.

Comment: Here's an example: http://www.zigdigital.com.br/download/descartar/Diagrama1-2013-12-12.jpeg

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i think you need to try like this,,try this

```
SELECT * 
FROM parent_table 
RIGHT OUTER JOIN child_table 
ON (parent_table_id = child_table_id) 
WHERE parent_table_id = ?
```

Comment: Same results. Take a look closer: http://www.zigdigital.com.br/download/descartar/Diagrama1-2013-12-12.jpeg

Comment: i have tested it on my system  ,it is giving me correct result ,, plz let me know what is your exact query,,and it is very much helpfull if you give the snapshot of tables

Comment: I'm sorry. Your query is correct. My description of the problem was wrong. Its not 1:1, it's 1:N relationship. The result should be one in the parent_table and many in the child_table.